# What is the cleanest way to convert this object into an array of key-pair objects?

Tags: javascript

I have an object below, that I need in the following format. I can't seem to get the named pairs working. Happily to accept lodash answers as well. Thanks

```js
const object = {
  "mobile": "04000000",
  "address": "123 fake st"
}
```

That I need to turn into this format.

```js
const format = [
  {
    name: "mobile",
    value: "04000000"
  },
  {
    name: "address",
    value: "123 fake st"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the key/value pairs of the object as an array, and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to construct the object for each item:

```js
const object = {
    "mobile": "04000000",
    "address": "123 fake st"
}


const res = Object.entries(object).map(e => ({name: e[0], value: e[1]}))

console.log(res)
```